# Disallow specific types for a TypeVar in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting, restriction

Is there any way to make it so that a **Python TypeVar** is **not allowed** to be bound to **some types**?

I'm aware that you can restrict the TypeVar to some types, have an upper bound or mark it as covariant/contravariant/invariant, but there doesn't seem to be a way to say "The TypeVar is not allowed to be these types".

Essentially what I would like to say is something like `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<NotAllowedType, T>>` in C++.

For example, *T* should never be an *Exception*:

```
from typing import Union, Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class Expected(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value_or_error: Union[T, Exception]):
        self._value_or_error = value_or_error

    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        return not isinstance(self._value_or_error, Exception)
```

but there's not a straightforward way that comes to mind to enforce this. 
As far as I know most generics (e.g. Java, Scala, Kotlin) don't support this, but maybe I'm missing something or there's a workaround(?).

Comment: I don't think there is a way, but you can [open an issue in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/new)

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do in the end, but I'm making sure I'm not missing something obvious(and waste contributor's time) first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, looks like this is not supported currently: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/599